# Spark - Scala - Remove Columns from a dataframe based on condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

We have a specific need wherein I will have to `drop` columns from a `dataframe` which has only one unique value in that column. The following is what we are doing

```
val rawdata = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").load(filename)
```

Subsequently to find unique values in all columns we are using the `HyperLog++` algorithm supported in spark

```
val cd_cols  = rawdata.select(rawdata.columns.map(column => approxCountDistinct(col(column)).alias(column)): _*)
```

The output is

```
scala> cd_cols.show
+----+----------+---------+---+---------+--------------+---------+----------+----------------+---------+--------------+-------------+
|  ID|First Name|Last Name|Age|Attrition|BusinessTravel|DailyRate|Department|DistanceFromHome|Education|EducationField|EmployeeCount|
+----+----------+---------+---+---------+--------------+---------+----------+----------------+---------+--------------+-------------+
|1491|       172|      154| 43|        2|             3|      913|         3|              30|        1|             6|            1|
+----+----------+---------+---+---------+--------------+---------+----------+----------------+---------+--------------+-------------+
```

Notice that I have two columns which has a 1 as the unique value. I want to create another `dataframe` which has all columns except those two columns (`Education` and `EmployeeCount`)

I tried using a for loop, but was not very happy and also tried

```
cd_cols.columns.filter(colName => cd_cols.filter(colName) <= 1)
```

that is also not working.

Is there a smarter way to do this please.

Thanks

Bala

Comment: if you don't want those columns then just select the rest of the columns.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, i won't know it before hand. It all depends on the unique values that the previous statement returns. I cannot 'hard-code' those columns.

Comment: So it means that you want to drop those columns which has 1 value?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Yes. Dropping columns which has only ONE unique value

Comment: Is it true that by looking at one row, we can know which columns to drop? I mean to say is it symmetric that if a column in a row is 1 then all the rest of the rows will be 1 in that particular column?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, please see the statement above that drop column requirement. I am doing a distinctcount. if DistinctCount of any columns returns 1, that means we have only one unique value (across all rows) in that column. Want to drop that column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try the following command:

```
df.selectExpr(df.first().getValuesMap[Int](df.columns).filter(_._2 != 1).keys.toSeq: _*).show
```

Here we are first taking the first row of the `dataframe` and converting it into a map using `getValueMap` with the column names and just filtering the columns whose value is not 1.

Comment: That worked like charm. A small correction i had to make was to change that [Int] to [Long]. 

val select_cols = df.selectExpr(df.first().getValuesMap[Long](df.columns).filter(_._2 != 1).keys.toSeq: _*)

Thank you so much for the help

Comment: What is _._2? is this the column name?

Comment: _._2 is the second element of the tuple

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go on from what you were originally trying, the following should also work.  Also, note that with Spark 2.0 onwards you can pass a list into drop and remove the columns that way.  This may be more clear as to what you are doing.

Or worst case is another way of doing it.

This should work with most spark versions.

```
    val keptCols: Seq[Column] = df.columns
      .map(c => (c, df.select(c).first.getLong(0)))
      .filter{case (c, v) => v!=1}
      .map{case (c, v) => df(c)}
      .toSeq

    df.select(keptCols: _*).show
```

For > Spark 2.0

```
    val droppedCols: Seq[String] = df.columns
      .map(c => (c, df.select(c).first.getLong(0)))
      .filter{case (c, v) => v==1}
      .map{case (c, v) => c}
      .toSeq

    df.drop(droppedCols: _*).show
```

Both should use the same results.